# Troubleshooting javascript failed

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a page: http://concours.quebecskialliance.com/francais.html. It only works in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome. The button, made with a jQuery .button is not created, which lead me to a JavaScript error, but even with JSLint or Chrome console developers tool I cannot find what's wrong.

Note: to work there should be a big box in the upper right part, full of images

Comment: "The button, make with a jquery .button is not created". Where should it be? can you provide two screenshots, one working and one not and a better explanation?

Comment: does this help? This is what I see in chrome dev console uncaught syntax error: unexpected string canvas-and-more-fr.js:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might just be my average knowledge of jQuery speaking but this with the period seems strange

```
var tovalidate  = $.('#friend_email_input').val();
```

shouldn't it be

```
var tovalidate  = $('#friend_email_input').val();
```

that's the line that IE's debugger is erroring out over..

Comment: good catch.. but this function is no longer in use !...

Comment: still dont work : i still got think funky error  : Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.